# How do I create a 'picture gallery' with pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pagination

I want my web page to look something like this: http://1x.com/photos/latest-additions/

I nearly mirrored it using only PHP (code found below). However, I decided I need to have a database after people from stackoverflow told me I need to, as it will be good in the long run. Anyways, so now I'm at a loss, learning MySQL. I want to make my page be very similar to that 1x page: with clickable pictures in a certain order (except I want to use a list instead of a table, for better web semantics), and pagination. Can somebody please tell how I can achieve this? I don't intend to be a programmer, I just want to know how to make that layout + pagination :[

Can somebody please help? (by giving me a script, or tell me exactly what to do)

Oh, and

This was my original code. You can skip this, it's not necessary.

```
<?php
$rows_per_page = 2;
$cols_per_page = 2;
$image_href = '<a href=/';
$image_links = array('comics/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>', 'otherstuff/randy>');
$img_srcs = '<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagetitle/';
$images = array();

for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $images[$i] = $i;
}
$image_ending = '.png" height="200" width="200" /></a>';
$image_break = '<br /><div class="timeago"><div id="submitted">submitted&nbsp;</div>';
$image_descriptions = array('<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>', '<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-03-13T07:24:17Z"></abbr></div>');  
$total_images = count($images);
$images_per_page = $rows_per_page * $cols_per_page;
$total_images = count($images);
$total_pages = ceil($total_images / $images_per_page);
$current_page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if($current_page<1 || $current_page>$total_pages)
{
    $current_page = 1;
}

//Get records for the current page
$page_image_links = array_splice($image_links, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$page_images = array_splice($images, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$page_image_descriptions = array_splice($image_descriptions, ($current_page-1)*$images_per_page, $images_per_page);
$slots = "<table border=\"0\">";
for($row=0; $row<$rows_per_page; $row++)
{
    $slots .= "<tr>";
    for($col=0; $col<$cols_per_page; $col++)
    {
        $imgIdx = ($row * $rows_per_page) + $col;
        $img = (isset($page_images[$imgIdx])) ? "{$image_href}{$page_image_links[$imgIdx]}{$img_srcs}{$page_images[$imgIdx]}{$image_ending}{$image_break}{$page_image_descriptions[$imgIdx]}" : '&nbsp;';
        $slots .= "<td class='tables'>$img</td>";
    }
    $slots .= "</tr>";
}
$slots .= "</table>";

//Create pagination links
$first = "First";
$prev  = "Prev";
$next  = "Next";
$last  = "Last";
if($current_page>1)
{
    $prevPage = $current_page - 1;
    $first = "<a href=\"w4rmoemfdoiemroifmeromfxdnxvl.php?page=1\">First</a>";
    $prev  = "<a href=\"w4rmoemfdoiemroifmeromfxdnxvl.php?page={$prevPage}\">Prev</a>";
}
if($current_page<$total_pages)
{
    $nextPage = $current_page + 1;
    $next = "<a href=\"w4rmoemfdoiemroifmeromfxdnxvl.php?page={$nextPage}\">Next</a>";
    $last = "<a href=\"w4rmoemfdoiemroifmeromfxdnxvl.php?page={$total_pages}\">Last</a>";
}

?>
<html>
<title></title>
<head><style type="text/css">
#submitted {color: #888888; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: .8em; float:left;}
.tables {padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;}
.timeago {color: #888888; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: .8em; float:right;}
</style><script src="/static/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});</script></head>
<body>
<h2>Here are the records for page <?php echo $current_page; ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php echo $slots; ?>
  </ul>
Page <?php echo $current_page; ?> of <?php echo $total_pages; ?>
<br />
<?php echo "view more: {$next}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to do this on your own which is plausible as it will allow you to learn something new, look for resources on:
1. connecting to a mysql database table from php
2. getting data from db into some variable
3. sending data from page to page using the querystring
4. post and get
for advanced stuff learn about sending asynchronous calls and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

For being not a programmer, why do you want to write code yourself (or even ask someone to write it for you)?
There are plenty of ready made gallery suites like [Menalto Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/), [Coppermine Galler](http://coppermine-gallery.net/)y and such.
Those consists of way more professional code than some sketch you can get from a volunteer on Stackoverflow.

Just download yourself one and play around. I am sure it will suit all your needs

Comment: Thing is, I need to customize the gallery. I understand how php works when I look at the code, but I can't for the live of me, understand how to start coding. You know what I mean? So yeah, I really am looking for sketches from stack more so than professionally made galleries.

Comment: @user657847 you know, you can customize these galleries all right.

Comment: Well, can you tell me if it's easy to create an image gallery? I'd be willing to learn if I had a good estimate of how long it'll take me to get to that point.

Comment: @user657847 for the good gallery like I mentioned above it's ages. for the small one it depends on your skills. for me it's like couple hours. Last time I made a small gallery of 30 lines of code. but for you it will take too long to afford. don't forget, you have to learn PHP at the same time. Even such a trivial thing like pagination is a big problem for you. And there are hundreds problems to solve.

Comment: I think you're really underestimating the skill/experience I already have lol. I mean, I know how to make a purely gallery, as shown above. I just don't know how to move that over to a database... Why do I need a database? In case I have like 10000imgs, it would be better to store in a database, rather than have a huge a array containing all my img srcs and hrefs.

Comment: @user657847 1. it's your own words I estimate. it's impossible to write a complex program not being a programmer. 2. you can't store pictures in array. array is a PHP variable and it's lifetime is like 0.01 sec. But you don't need it anyway, as you have all your pictures on the disk and you can read the names on demand. Don't tell me that you gonna put 10k pictures into single album. 3. For the small gallery it would be better to avoid database as unnecessary complexity. 4. how to make pagination from db is a VERY common question, I answered 2 times since last week, with comprehensive example.

Comment: Ohhhh wow now that I hear myself, I think you got it all wrong. I'm not trying to create a program. Far from it. It's not gonna be a huge database. I just want a page where I can put up pictures easily (like just insert the a href and img src to my database, and it'll show on my page). It should function EXACTLY like the code I provided above. That's it. No programs. I've got Larry Ullman's PHP 6 and MySQL 5 for Dynamic Web Sites: Visual QuickPro Guide  to boot, but I haven't read that far into it (schooling gets in the way). Anyway, does what I say now seem easily feasible? Please say yes...

Comment: @user657847 this code above is already a program. "I just want a page where I can put up pictures easily" does not sound like sensible description. I have such a page of my own, but I doubt it will suit you: it uses no thumbnails but jst showing all pictures found in the catalog, one by one, using mouse wheel or hyperlinks to move. that's all. And it fit's into your description. If you want to have a program, you have to create technical documentation first :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I always write my comments in a hurry. I just want a script that does EXACTLY what my php code above does. You can run it on your text editor to see what I mean. It's rather simple. The only difference is I want to store my links and img srcs in a database so my pages would theoretically run faster. That's all. It seems like such a simple task >.< .

Comment: @user657847 so, you're asking someone to write a code for you because current one may be theoretically slow? There was an old man named Donald Knuth, and he said once "Premature optimization as the root of all evil". In your place I'd relax and left everything as is.

Comment: You have no idea how much that applies to me. I've spent so much time researching how to optimize my site ever so slightly. Example: I spent a week just trying to figure out why my htaccess code which makes .php unnecessary wasn't working for my /blog.php . It worked for all other pages. Rather than just deciding to have a mod_rewrite redirecting /blog to blog.php, I slaved away a full week just finding out why, all bc I didn't want an extra line on my htaccess redirecting, since I thought the fewer the lines, the faster. Seriously :O.   Anyways, I'll still try to figure this out >.<.